# Convery array of strings to array of objects - every 3rd index

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert an array of strings to an array of objects after every 3rd index.

Input:

```
let tee = [
  'Blue',             '130',
  '70.8',             'Blue',
  '128',              '708',
  'White',            '124',
  '68.2'
]
```

Code:

```
            function fillTeeBoxes(holesAmount) {
            for (let i = 0; i < holesAmount.length; i++) {
                let teeBox = ['tee', 'slope', 'rating']
                let holeData = {};
                for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    holeData[teeBox[j]] = parseInt(getTeeBoxes[i]) || getTeeBoxes[i]
                    i++
                };
                teeBoxes.push(holeData)
            };
        };
```

Expected Output:

```
    tee = [
      {tee: 'Blue', slope: 130, handicap: 70.8}
      {tee: 'Blue', slope: 128, handicap: 70.8}
      {tee: 'White', slope: 124, handicap: 68.2}
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a for loop and iterate in steps of 3:

```js
let tee = [
  'Blue',             '130',
  '70.8',             'Blue',
  '128',              '708',
  'White',            '124',
  '68.2'
];
var output = [];

for (var i=0; i < tee.length; i+=3) {
    var obj = {tee:tee[i], slope:tee[i+1], handicap:tee[i+2]};
    output.push(obj);
}

console.log(output);
```